# Is there a name for the mazelike part of a forest?

Tags: single-word-requests

In forests there are places like groves, but with a minor amount of bushes and small plants. It is possible to pass through it, but the bushes make it seem as if there are many paths in the zone, making it confusing and easy to get lost in like a maze.

Does this part of the forest have a name in English?

Example sentences:

- "We got lost in the ________"
- "He avoided the _______ for fear of getting lost in its false paths"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Thicket-mazes and tanglewoods

If you are looking only for general terms composed of common, immediately recognizable components like *brambles* and *briars*, then you should go for ***thicket-maze*** or perhaps ***tanglewood***.

Both terms occur as both open and closed compounds, sometimes with hyphens. The OED provides these citations for them:

- 1837   Arthur Penrhyn Stanley *The Gipsies* 136
     Or track old Jordan through his **thicket maze**.
- 1894   *Chicago Advance* 26 Apr.
     He scuttled off in a wild panic through the thick **tanglewood**.

I think those are your two best choices, and I would not hesitate to use either in any context at all.

But there are many, many other possibilities, depending on what best suits your own particular purpose and context.

## Local colo(u)r

If you are seeking more localized terms from certain corners of the world, or from certain times other than our own, then any number of terms for *leaf-whelmed glens* or *denes* are available, such as *copsy, bosket, perthog, roughet, frith*. There are dozens more where those came from.

Here are a couple such, the first from the New World and the second from the Old, along with a bit of detail for each:

- A *shinnery* is “a type of low brush thicket..difficult or impossible to cross
  on foot or horseback...taking its name from the shin oak (*Quercus havardii*).”
- A *spinney* is “A small wood or copse, esp. one planted or preserved for sheltering game-birds; a small clump or plantation of trees.”

Most of these are mainly used in quaintly cultivated lands, not for the *wildwood* proper, which is “a natural woodland unaffected by Neolithic or later civilization”.

## Wand’ring the forests primeval

For something more suited to wildwoods like the Amazonian jungles of South America, the Daintree rainforest of far north Queensland in Australia, or the impenetrable Tongass rainforest along the Pacific coast of North America, you probably want something with darker and possibly more literary overtones.

Think, for example, of the enchanted paths of Mirkwood that so bewildered Bilbo Baggins and his company of dwarves in *The  Hobbit*, or of the *selva selvaggia* that caused the traveller at the start of Dante’s *Inferno* to lose his way, I imagine that rather more sinister or ancient terms might be chosen here — like *dwimordene*, perhaps.

But I hesitate to delve into any of these other possibilities without knowing more about your intended use.

Comment: Lovely answer that covers all the forest types  Nice to see the Middle-Earthian _dwimordene_.

Answer (score 7):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but "thicket" may come close. From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thicket):

> a dense growth of shrubbery or small trees : COPSE

A thicket does not have to be "mazelike", but it could be. It would work in both of your example sentences. (In fact, [a Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lost%20in%20the%20thicket%22&biw=1536&bih=751&tbm=bks) turns up many examples of the exact phrase "lost in the thicket".)

Answer (score -2):

[Brake](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brake)

Etymology 3

From Old English bracu, first attested in plural form fearnbraca (“thickets of fern”),
probably from Proto-Germanic *brekaną (“to break”) and influenced by sense 2 (“fern”).
Compare Middle Low German brake (“stump, branch”).

Noun

Brake (plural brakes)

A thicket, or an area overgrown with briers etc. [from 15th c.]

Example sentences

1593, [William Shakespeare], Venus and Adonis, London: […] Richard Field, […], OCLC 837166078; Shakespeare’s Venus & Adonis: […], 4th edition, London: J[oseph] M[alaby] Dent and Co. […], 1896, OCLC 19803734:

- Rounds rising hillocks, brakes obscure and rough, / To shelter thee from tempest and from rain.

1808 February 22, Walter Scott, in Marmion; a Tale of Flodden Field, Edinburgh: […] J[ames] Ballantyne and Co. for Archibald Constable and Company, […]; London: William Miller, and John Murray, OCLC 270129616:

- He stayed not for brake, and he stopped not for stone.

1807, William Wordsworth, Poems, Fidelity:

```
    He halts, and searches with his eyes
    Among the scatter'd rocks:
    And now at distance can discern
    A stirring in a brake of fern […]
```

1859, George Meredith, The Ordeal of Richard Feverel, Chapter 5:

- The bird, with its fellow in the break, drummed, and whirred, and to the misfortune of its species made its plumage seem a prize to them.

[Underbrush](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/underbrush) (Synonym: Undergrowth)

Underbrush consists of bushes and plants growing close together under trees in a forest.

- consists of bushes and plants growing close together under trees in a forest.
- small trees, bushes, ferns, etc, growing beneath taller trees in a wood or forest
- the condition of being undergrown
- shrubs, saplings, low vines, etc., growing under the large trees in a wood or forest

Examples of 'underbrush' in a sentence

- She saw his back rushing into the trees, heard him in the underbrush, and saw... a shed at the edge of the clearing.
  Wood, Bari DOLL'S EYES (2001)
- Here and there he could sense animals rustling through the underbrush.
  Kerr, Katharine A TIME OF WAR (2001)
- Sometimes she dozed off and followed Father Damien through the underbrush.
  Louise Erdrich THE LAST REPORT ON THE MIRAC

Comment: Whenever you suggest a word with a link, also give 1) an explanation of why it is appropriate (it's not always obvious to everybody why the suggestion is relevant), and 2) the definition at that link (it's common courtesy to save people the time of clicking the link (they can click if they want more details) and links don't last forever.